# Check value range in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

```
[ { start_time: '1', end_time: '10' },
  { start_time: '3', end_time: '15' } ]
```

These object are multiple...

This is my time range array, if the first object has `start_time` 1 and `end_time` is 10 then the second object `start_time`, not between in 1 to 10.

I want the second object `start_time` greater than the first object `end_time`.

**Expected output.**

```
[ { start_time: '1', end_time: '10' },
{ start_time: '11', end_time: '15' } ]
```

Comment: You can't, at least not with the provided data.

Comment: Please check expected output.

Comment: hey @HirdeshSingh! can you show us what you tried so far? so we can guide you further?

Comment: How are the output values related to the input values? This doesn't make any sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to traverse through object elements and modify data if its less than what you need:

```js
var data = [ { start_time: '1', end_time: '10' },
  { start_time: '3', end_time: '15' } ] ;
  
var temp = null;
for(var index=0; index< data.length; index++) {
   if (temp && parseInt(data[index].start_time) <= parseInt(temp)) {
      data[index].start_time = (parseInt(temp)+1).toString();
   }
   temp = data[index].end_time;
} 

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary variable (say time) and compare start_time and time before push to new updated array.

```js
const data = [
  { start_time: "1", end_time: "10" },
  { start_time: "3", end_time: "15" }
];

let time = -Infinity;
const updated = [];

data.forEach(({ start_time, end_time }) => {
  updated.push({ start_time: String(Math.max(time, start_time)), end_time });
  time = Number(end_time) + 1;
});

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Thank you but I want if first object start_time is 1 and end_time is 10 then all other objects must have start_time greater then the end_time of the first object if it is not then it must return an error.

Comment: @HirdeshSingh You should mention this explicitly in your question. This is not the place to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 var arr = [ 
   { start_time: '1', end_time: '10'},
   { start_time: '3', end_time: '9'},
   { start_time: '5', end_time: '10'},
   { start_time: '10', end_time: '15'} 
 ];

 var modifiedArr = arr.map((item, index)=>{ return checkObject(item,index);})

 function checkObject(item, index) {
  if(index == 0) return item;
  let prevItem = arr[index-1];
  if(parseInt(item.start_time) < parseInt(prevItem.end_time)){
    item.start_time = parseInt(prevItem.end_time) + 1;
  }
  if(parseInt(item.end_time) <= parseInt(item.start_time)){
   item.end_time = parseInt(item.start_time) + 1;
  }

  return item;
 }
 console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some initial code with simple if condition code. You can refer it whether it will work for you. kindly check the following code.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < obj.length - 1; i++) {
     if (Number(obj[i + 1].start_time) <= Number(obj[i].end_time)) {
         alert("start_time must be greater than previous end_time");
     }
 }
```